# Edit the_category (); for a hierarchical display

Tags: php, functions, categories, tags, hierarchical

For my wp theme I want to use the categories as tags on my posts.
Example:
[image]

The problem is that the category in red must always be the parent and in gold the child.

Except that  returns the categories to me in alphabetical order and not in hierarchical order, so sometimes I end up with the child in red and the parent in gold ...

Knowing that I would only use 2 categories per posts so 1 = the parent and 2 = the child

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign the post only to the child category, and call the function like so:

```php
the_category( ' ', 'multiple' );
```

This will output (notice the whitepsace between the anchor tags):

```html
<a href="https://example.com/category/parent/">parent</a> <a href="https://example.com/category/parent/child/" rel="category tag">child</a>
```

Comment: It's almost functional but it shows me:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/category/parent/">Parent</a>
<a href="https://example.com/category/parent/child/" rel="category tag">Child</a>
<a href="https://example.com/category/parent/" rel="category tag">Parent</a>
```

Comment: You probably have the post assigned to multiple categories, instead of only the child category.

Comment: Thank you ! it works

Comment: Neat! Please mark the answer as accepted if it works, so it may help other users.

Comment: @Maximus taxonomy terms are inclusive, they aren't a tree of connected boxes, they're a nest of nested boxes, a category contains all the posts in its sub-categories so you don't have to check the parent category too